# How to have a SBT subproject depending on the root project?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to use [mdoc](https://scalameta.org/mdoc) in a simple SBT single-project build ([link](https://github.com/ruippeixotog/akka-testkit-specs2)). mdoc requires me to create a subproject for the documentation, but I'd like to avoid moving all the code to a subfolder. I was trying to create a docs subproject that depends on the root project:

```scala
lazy val core = project.in(file("."))
lazy val docs = project.in(file("docs")).dependsOn(core)
```

However, this makes SBT try to find a JAR for my root project (obviously not finding it):

```
(sbt) core ❯ docs/compile
[info] Updating
[info] Resolved  dependencies
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run last docs / update for the full output
[error] (docs / update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading net.ruippeixotog:akka-testkit-specs2_2.12:0.3.0-SNAPSHOT
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: /Users/rui/.ivy2/local/net.ruippeixotog/akka-testkit-specs2_2.12/0.3.0-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/ruippeixotog/akka-testkit-specs2_2.12/0.3.0-SNAPSHOT/akka-testkit-specs2_2.12-0.3.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed Dec 28, 2019 11:27:50 PM
```

With other subproject deps (e.g. if I make the `core` project point to another folder) SBT adds a direct classpath dependency to the subproject's `target/` folder. Why is the root project handled differently? Is there another way to make this work?

Comment: May be it will work after `sbt publishLocal`. But it's not good solution if you often generate docs

Comment: lazy val core = project.dependsOn(util)

Comment: @MikhailIonkin yes, creating the JAR each time I want to generate documentation is not an option unfortunately :(